# ts: Type must have a Symbol.iterator when trying to push to array conditionally

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to add an item conditionally into an array:

```
  fields: [
    ...formPayload.fields.filter((field) => field !== oldValue),
    ...(!formPayload.fields.includes(newValue) ? newValue : null), //ERROR
    
  ],
```

But the last line gives the following error: `type string | null must have a Symbol.iterator method that returns an iterator`

If I replace the last line with

```
...newValue
```

It's working. What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: `...null` would be an error

Comment: Ohh right thanks for this, so I should replace null with [] right?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here. It seems like you're trying to append a new value but the spread indicates that `newValue` would be some iterable. Is that the case? If you just want to append one thing then you don't need the spread at all. If you do want to append multiple, then perhaps `.concat()` might be more appropriate..

Comment: Thanks for your help, I want to append a single value but only if it's defined

Comment: "*only if it's defined*" what do you mean by that? Right now you're checking whether `newValue` already exists in the array and if it is, then it's added again. So, with `["a", "b", "c"]` and `oldValue = "a"` and `newValue = "b"` you would get `["b", "c", "b"]` however `newValue = "d"` would result in `["b", "c"]`. Is that correct? Or do you mean that if the value is falsy, it should not be added? Or maybe that if it's not in the array, then it should be added?

Comment: I'm sorry if I gave you an headache, that was a syntax error, I'm checking it it exists and only adds it if it doesn't exist (I edited my question now), and if it doesn't exist then it shouldn't add anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the spread operator from the second line:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyTAtgApQCeESUwAXPAN44CWIEwaNAFJjAygObwAfeCgCuECAEoA2gF14AXwDcAKGWhIsBMnRYkLAGpQIIkDS49eK9dDiJUmYSADuh46fjm+K5bgLEyFMAAdNhMLGjwALzwUsrw8EGJvkSk5JQhYawZEBggMOzsoczAElEAfIzF8ACEkdF6wK4mEgA0cfCFeCkB6UXhQTyQIqBo7CjOTSClAPyOLkYm8DSi4q3KMipAA)

```ts
// before:
...(formPayload.fields.includes(newValue) ? newValue : null),
```

```ts
// after:
(formPayload.fields.includes(newValue) ? newValue : null),
```

And if you want no value at all instead of null, you can use this syntax:

```ts
...(formPayload.fields.includes(newValue) ? [newValue] : []),
```

Comment: If OP wants to spread `newValue`, then that's not equivalent

Comment: @VLAZ OP didn't say what type `newValue` is, but based on what's present, I guess it isn't iterable.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I didn't mention that yes if value is falsy then I'd like not to add it, in this case I should just replcae null with [] in the original syntax?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73772095/ts-type-must-have-a-symbol-iterator-when-trying-to-push-to-array-conditionally/73772140#comment130266295_73772140) @sir-haver If that's the desired behavior, then yes.

Comment: @sir-haver See update for how to omit the value entirely instead of including null

Comment: Yes I understand this perfectly now thank you very much